# show progress during renaming and moving image files using WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am currently having problems showing a progress bar while waiting for image files to be renamed. I've tried several progress bar tutorials and answers but am having trouble plugging them into my project.

Here's the code I have so far:(I am very much a novice)
I removed the progress bar for now since i can't get it to work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace Change_Image_file_name
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\USB Archive Photos";
        string destinationFolder = @"C:\New USB Archive\";
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
                int i = 1;

                if (Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
                {
                    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(destinationFolder), File.Delete);
                    
                    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
                    {
                        string imageName = i.ToString();
                        Directory.Move(file.FullName, destinationFolder + imageName + ".jpg");
                        i++;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("The images have been renamed and moved to the New USB Archive folder");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please add a New USB Archive folder on the root of C:");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please add a USB Archive Photos folder on the root of C:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a progress bar and it seems to work, but not sure if this is really the correct way to implement it.

```
namespace progress_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DoWorkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            ProgressTextBlock.Text = (string)e.UserState;
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           
            var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            worker.ReportProgress(0, String.Format("Processing Iteration 1."));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                worker.ReportProgress((i + 1) * 10, String.Format("Processing Iteration {0}.", i + 2));
            }

            worker.ReportProgress(100, "Done Processing.");

            string sourceFolder = @"C:\USB Archive Photos";
            string destinationFolder = @"C:\New USB Archive\";
            //private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
                    int i = 1;

                    if (Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
                    {
                        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(destinationFolder), File.Delete);

                        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
                        {
                            string imageName = i.ToString();
                            Directory.Move(file.FullName, destinationFolder + imageName + ".jpg");
                            i++;
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("The images have been renamed and moved to the New USB Archive folder");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please add a New USB Archive folder on the root of C:");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please add a USB Archive Photos folder on the root of C:");
                }
            }
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
            TestProgressBar.Value = 0;
            ProgressTextBlock.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Progressbar? And what exactly is not working?

Comment: I removed it. Everything I tried was not working. So not even sure where I should try to call it in my code. When I did have a progress bar, it did nothing. With my app if you change the name and move several image files, let's say 50 or more, it can take a long time, and there is nothing happening on the screen for several seconds, which is about 10+ seconds in some cases.

Comment: Sorry to tell you this. But I can't review and fix what I don't see... This is all I can offer I guess [Progressbar example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.progressbar?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples). Also don't use `Directory.GetFiles()`. Use the `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` instead. It will give you better performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on it and add back the progress bar.